# Replace field with a custom one [ORACLE]

Tags: sql, oracle, case

`Problem:` I need to translate some errors into a select statement.

`Example:` I have a table with the following information:

```
 -----------------------
|ID   | NAME     | ERROR|
|-----------------------|
| 001 | example1 | err1 |
| 002 | example2 | err2 |
| 003 | example3 | err3 |
 -----------------------
```

Every mistake means:

```
err1: Login failed
err2: Failure of the database
err3: Hard drive full
```

I need to make a select statement that returns the information as follows:

```
 -----------------------------------------
|ID   | NAME     |      ERROR             |
|-----------------------------------------|
| 001 | example1 | Login failed           |
| 002 | example2 | Failure of the database|
| 003 | example3 | Hard drive full        |
 -----------------------------------------
```

`My intent`: I've tried the following:

```
SELECT *,
CASE
  WHEN error=err1  THEN 'Login failed'
  WHEN error=err2  THEN 'Failure of the database'
  WHEN error=err3  THEN 'Hard drive full'
END
FROM table;
```

Comment: what's the problem?  .. you have error ...  ?

Comment: yes i have this error: `ORA-00923 FROM keyword not found where expected`.

Comment: `select table.*, case... end as err from...`.

Comment: @jarlh Thank you very much was that.

Comment: @Randomuser1204281 - if you have additional columns in the output, you can't just use * in SELECT, you must prefix it with the table name (or an alias for the table name, if you create an alias in the FROM clause). With that out of the way, you will receive an INVALID IDENTIFIER error. Can you see why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT table.*,
CASE
  WHEN error='err1'  THEN 'Login failed'
  WHEN error='err2'  THEN 'Failure of the database'
  WHEN error='err3'  THEN 'Hard drive full'
END as NEW_ERROR
FROM table
```

Comment: This should not work either (even with the first syntax error fixed), because it has another mistake. I wonder if the OP tested this when he/she marked the answer "Correct". Can you spot the other mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to address this type of problems is NOT to hard-code the meaning of each error code in your query. Rather, you should have a small table, `error_codes`, with two columns, one for the error code and the other for the description. And then join your base table to this small table on the `error_code` column. Hard-coding will be faster, because it doesn't require a join, but it will be much harder to maintain. And especially so if you need to do this in more than just one query.